# Take NOT of Condition in Java String

Tags: java, conditional-statements, unary-operator

I have a Java String which has a Condition in it like ((#a==1 && #b==2 || #c==3) && (#d==4)). I want to take NOT (!) of this string.

Input String: `((#a==1 && #b==2 || #c==3) && (#d==4))`

Expected Output String: `(((#a!=1 || #b!=2) && (#c!=3)) || (#d!=4))`

If I have to implement it, then the first challenge that I see is correctly putting the parenthesis to the String and the tokenizing it according to a grammar. I am not sure how I can do these.

Comment: Look into using the ANTLR library.  You may define your own syntax/grammar, then parse your expression, and negate it.  There is no easy way to answer your question without doing some sort of parsing.

Comment: [**Questions asking us to recommend or find a** book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic** for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I would recommend you *research* how to parse an expression into an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), which can then be manipulated.

Comment: How fascinating! This is quite tedious, but you if you have many statements or long statements, you could:

Comment: put them in a file as text

Comment: Scan that file using while(Scanner.hasNext()){

Comment: Then have if statements:

Comment: String str = "";   String next = Scanner.next(); }

Answer (score 0):

If you have many expressions or long expressions, you could parse them as text by putting them in a text file, then scanning through it using Scanner. By the way, this is a fascinating question, glad you asked!

```
File expressions = new File(/*pathname*/);
File inverse = new File(/*pathname*/);
FileWriter fileWriter = new fileWriter(inverse);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(expressions);

while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String str = "";
    String next = scanner.next();
    if (next.equals("=="){
        str = "!=";
    }
    else if (next.equals("!="){
        str = "==";
    }
    else if (next.equals("||"){
        str = "&&";
    }
    else if (next.equals("&&"){
        str = "||";
    }
fileWriter.write(str)
}
```

This almost surely works, maybe the suggestion Tim made is better.
Like Tim said, your goal will likely be accomplished through some sort of parsing.